# Using spp. for taxa other than Genus

Tags: taxonomy

Can spp. be used for taxa other than genus ? For example Noctuidae spp. meaning certain genera in the Noctuidae family.

Comment: eric I think this is an interesting question, but I'll suggest you modify a bit: You ask" "`...meaning certain genera...`". "Spp." would *still* likely refer to *species* and not *genera* in the application you're asking about.